# Magento2: How to update products position in category via CSV?

Tags: magento-2.1, category, attributes, position

I want update product position attribute in category through the CSV feed.
Anyone have any idea OR sample CSV which can accomplish my requirement.

Comment: Are u got it ......?

Answer (score 3):

**In  controller file**

```
 public function execute()
        {
   $categoryId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('category');
            $fileName = $_FILES["upload-stock-csv"]["name"];
            $filetmpName = $_FILES["upload-stock-csv"]["tmp_name"];           

            if (isset($fileName) &&  (pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'csv')) {
                //Update product position using csv
                $positionUpdate = $this->_csvProcessor->getData($filetmpName);
                $this->_position->updatePositionUsingsku($categoryId, $positionUpdate);
            } else {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__("Please select the valid file format"));
            }
        }
```

**In Model file:**

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;

class Position
{

    protected $_messageManager;
    protected $_productRepository;
    protected $_categoryRepository;

    public function __construct(Category $categoryRepository, Product $productRepository, ResourceConnection $resourceConnection, ManagerInterface $messageManager)
    {
        $this->_categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->_getConnection = $resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $this->_categoryProductTable = $resourceConnection->getTableName('catalog_category_product');
    }


    public function updatePositionUsingsku($categoryId, $positionUpdate)
    {
        $adapter = $this->_getConnection;
        foreach ($positionUpdate as $row) {
            if ((trim($row[0]) == 'Sku') || (trim($row[0]) == 'SKU') || (trim($row[0]) == 'sku'))
                continue;
            $sku = trim($row[0]);
            $productPosition = trim($row[1]);
            //Update product position using csv
            if ($sku) {
                $productId = $this->_productRepository->getIdBySku($sku);
                if ($productId) {
                    $where = array(
                        'category_id = ?' => (int) $categoryId,
                        'product_id = ?' => (int) $productId
                    );
                    $position = $productPosition;
                    $bind = array('position' => (int) $position);
                    $adapter->update($this->_categoryProductTable, $bind, $where);
                    $this->_messageManager->addSuccess(__(' %1  Position Updated Successfully.', $sku));
                } else {
                    $this->_messageManager->addError(__("%1 is not available", $sku));
                }
            } else {
                $this->_messageManager->addError(__("sku is not available"));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please share csv format and this code where run